# Java GUI place layout under boxlayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jpanel

I have used `borderlayout` to specify where the content of my java GUI shall be placed, I have then chosen to place it on `EAST` and then made two `boxlayouts` to show two columns of buttons. I now have to place something underneath it and not beside it. How would you suggest or advice me to do so, using any layout but preferably `boxlayout` and not absolute layout(null). Thanks in advance.

**Image:**

[image]

The arrow points to the place I want another `JPanel` to be.

Comment: The order of your buttons is in disorder ;)

Comment: You could wrap your content that holds the two boxlayouts in another boxlayout so that your existing buttons are all in the first box of that layout.

Comment: @SebastianH LOL didn't even notice, I just made a fast example, however. If I have to let's say, make a panel as the same as I already have, underneath it, how would I do that, thanks.

Comment: So how would I make another boxlayout underneath it instead of beside it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could...

1. Wrap both of the button panels in a `JPanel`
2. Whatever component goes at the arrow, wrap in a `JPanel` with `GrigbagLayout` (just to center it).
3. Create another `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` that will hold the above panels. Use `CENTER` and `SOUTH`.
4. Give an `EmptyBorder` to the `SOUTH` panel, only specifying the top region and space it accordingly.

Really there are many ways to accomplish this. The key though is to nest `JPanels` and make use of the different layout managers with each, use `EmptyBorders` or stuts for empty spaces til you get your desired effect.  The possibilities are endless. I don't think there's one *right* answer. Since we don't have a runnable example, I say just try the above, and mix and match will you get what you want.

Comment: Would this be the simpliest way of adding the complete same JPanel just underneath? Is there no option such as telling the boxlayout to stay beneath another boxlayout?

Comment: Honestly, without seeing how things are currently layed out, it's hard to tell what will work for you. Like I said there are so many option. Instead of `BorderLayout` you could use a vertical `BoxLayout` a `GridLayout(0, 1)` or even a `GridBagLayout` for the entire thing. The key though is nesting `JPanel`. I don't think there's a way around that with standard layout managers.

Comment: It is impossible to show a "simpliest" way without complete information how your whole GUI should look like. Your screenshot suggests that there may be more panels in the window - that massively influences what would be a good way to add the panel "below".

Comment: I was just seeking for options, thanks for the suggestions :)